# How do you open an audio file in mpv using the terminal without the album art opening along with it?

Tags: audio, terminal, archlinux, mpv

I have an arch linux based ditro and I'm trying to open up an audio file (mp3 and flac files) in the terminal using the following command:

```
$ mpv song.flac
```

If the audio file doesn't contain any album art, it opens up in the terminal and starts playing like I want it to. When the audio file does have album art though, it opens up a new window displaying the album art while playing the song. Is there a command I can enter or a setting I can change so I can play my audio files in the terminal without a new window being opened to display the album art?

Answer (score 10):

**mpv** comes with a flag to disable the display of cover art:

`$ mpv --audio-display=no song.flac`

does just what you want.
See the relevant documentation [here](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options-audio-display).

Comment: I prefer `--audio-display=no` over `--no-video` because with this option you still get video for files like `*.mp4`

Answer (score 8):

If you browse the "Video" section of the man page for mpv, you will see this very near the top:

> **−−no−video**
> Do not play video. With some demuxers this may not work. In those cases you can try −−vo=null instead.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest option I can find appears to be [`-vid=no`](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options-vid): `$ mpv -vid=no song.flac`.

Variants include `-vid no`, `--vid=no`, `--video=no`, `-no-vid` and `--no-video`.

`-vid=0` may seem like it works, but the thumbnail shows up again after a track change.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04 only.